# Run shell command from priv-app application

Tags: android, shell, android-source

I am trying to run shell commands from a system/priv-app I have added to the AOSP (7.1.1)

The command I am trying to run is: **ip link add dev can0 type can** to switch on the can bus.

I have build the image as both **-eng** & **-userdebug** releases.
The command runs fine in the adb shell and successfully switches on the CAN bus as expected.

My problem is that I get the following error:

> Cannot run program "su": error=13, Permission denied

When I try the following code within the system privileged java app:

```
//ArrayList<String> commands is passed into the method
try {
  if (null != commands && commands.size() > 0) {
     Process suProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
     DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(suProcess.getOutputStream());
     for (String currCommand : commands) {
        os.writeBytes(currCommand + "\n");
        os.flush();
     }
     os.writeBytes("exit\n");
     os.flush();
     BufferedReader stderr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(suProcess.getErrorStream()));
     String line = "";
     String errString = "";
     while ((line = stderr.readLine()) != null) errString += line + "\n";
     suProcess.waitFor();
     if (suProcess.exitValue() != 0)
        throw new Exception(errString);
 } //Handle exception
```

Comment: What is `ls -l /system/xbin/su` output?

Comment: `-rwsr-x--- 1 root shell 18000 2017-09-25 07:55 /system/xbin/su` I have tried to chmod this file in init.rc to give user execute permissions but that doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: So `su` is owned by `root` and `shell`- grouped. Your app which is `system`-grouped has no rights to execute it... What would I try is to: 1) `shell` into, get `su` and `chmod` the binary to be world-executable (you might need to remount `/system` in `rw` with `adb remount`); 2) if acceptable, install `SuperSU` or the alternatives to get `su` granted through those; 3) can't think of one :)

Comment: have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/46018625/1028256 - it may be that access to su is blocked by SE enforcing status.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to do it in this way:

```
Process mProcess = new ProcessBuilder()
                       .command("/system/xbin/su")
                       .redirectErrorStream(true).start();

DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(mProcess.getOutputStream());
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply however I am still receiving the same error with this method "D ERR: Cannot run program "/system/xbin/su": error=13, Permission denied"